# json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) appears after sending precisely 56 requests

Tags: python, json, solr, python-requests

I am sending multiple get requests to solr, and I'm changing the suffix of the url in each. All this is happening in a for loop.

```
li = ['first sentence', 'second sentence', 'third sentence', ...]

for count, item in enumerate(li):
    print('iteration:', count)
    url = '''http://someurl/'''
    url += item.join('%20')

    val = requests.get(url, verify=False, auth=HTTPBasicAuth('user', 'paSSW0rd'))

    print(val.json())
```

The list has a length of about 200, and the loop runs just fine for 56 iterations, but on the 56th iteration, I get the error

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Since the list is of length about 200, I also did li = li[57:] before the loop and ran the loop. The loop still gives the error after exactly 56 iterations.

Comment: Maybe there is a quote or a weird character in the 56th element?

Comment: There's nothing special about the 56th element. The point is that the iterations always stop after 56. So for example, if I start li from the 1st element rather than 0th element, the url that was giving the error before no longer gives the error, and instead the next one gives the error. I tried this with multiple starting points. It always gives the error after the 56th iteration.

Comment: What happens if you run the loop with a harcoded url ? eg. identical requests querying for 'first%20sentence'

Comment: your code seems fine, can you share the url so that I can try it on my system?

Comment: @EricLavault Actually with a hardcoded url this works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

First, use a `POST` request instead - when exceed a certain length of the URL, the HTTP server will reject the request. Solr will handle a POST request in exactly the same way as a GET request.

Second, Solr [has a `maxBooleanClauses` setting that you can set to a larger value](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/query-settings-in-solrconfig.html) in `solrconfig.xml` if necessary. Its default value is `1000`, which is enough for most queries - but if you have many, many terms, you'll cross that limit.

The Solr log will show you an exception that tells you exactly which of these two you've hit. The error message from python tells you that something occured on the other end that caused Solr to return something other than the regular JSON response (such as as a `500 Internal Server Error`).

Comment: I tried the post request. Even the first url doesn't go through this time.

Comment: Look at the Solr log - it should tell you what the issue is and why it's failing in that case. Also, there are multiple other characters in a URL that needs to be escaped outside of ` ` - such as `&` etc. You can use the `params={'q': ..}` argument to `.get` to get them properly escaped (instead of inserting `%20` manually).

Comment: I didn't change the code or anything, but magically it started working.